# Can we use firebase console to upload images manually?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage, android-glide

In my app , I have to display images in RecyclerView from Firebase database but the problem is I don't want to upload images using my app but I want them to be manually added using console of Firebase storage and later use their location to be added in Firebase database. I tried doing this way but glide is not loading the images. So is there any way to upload images manually and load images in app ?

Edited :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ITkq.png)
Look at my image, I have simply added the storage location of image in my database table. After then I am using those functions to get the image location and loading them with the help of glide library.

Here is my code of retrieving categories from Firebase database.

```
fun getCategories() : List<Categories>{
    val categoriesList = mutableListOf<Categories>()
    CoroutineScope(IO).launch {
           databaseReference.child("categories")
               .addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {

                   override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                       for (postSnapshot in dataSnapshot.children) {
                           val categories = postSnapshot.getValue(Categories::class.java)
                           categoriesList.add(categories!!)
                       }
                   }

                   override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {

                   }
               })
    }
    return categoriesList
}
```

And after retrieving categories list ,I am loading my Images in Adapter class. Here is my Adapter class code

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val model = modelList[position]
    holder.nameOfFruit?.text = model.name
    holder.nameOfFruit?.setOnClickListener {
        it.findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_mainFragment_to_choiceSelectedFragmentModel)
    }
        Glide.with(myContext!!).load(model.url).into(holder.imageOfFruit)
}
```

Edited : It is my image URL stored in my database.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LtI5K.png)

Comment: Images uploaded by the console should behave no differently than if uploaded from a mobile client.

Comment: They are uploading correctly but the images are not loading using glide , I checked the storage location of images and hit the url to browser but I ain't able to see any image .. if I use any other source image url like YouTube images url and replace the images url with it then I able to load YouTube images using glide.. I think all problem arises in my firebase storage url stored in database .

Comment: Without seeing code and actual data, we have no idea if you might be doing something incorrectly.

Comment: I Edited my question, Now u can check what i am doing wrong.

Comment: We still can't see examples of actual data you're working with.

Comment: Re read my question , i made some changes there. Also i used a snapshot to show the storage location that i am storing in my database. If you still didn't get anything, then let me know...

Comment: The problem is that we can't see if the URL you're working with in code actually matches the one that would load the image.

Comment: okay, ill upload another snapshot of my Firebase database

Comment: @DougStevenson I share a snapshot of my image URL stored in my database table. Please check it again..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've stored a "gs://" URL in your database.  This is a special Cloud Storage URL that only works with Google infrastructure.  It will not work in browsers or applications.

You will have to instead store a [download URL](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files#download_data_via_url) in the database.  If you've done it correctly, it will start with "https://".

Comment: As i said earlier, I ain't uploading images using my application code, I am doing this manually using Firebase Storage Console. So Is there any way to make it work like this.

Comment: You will have to somehow create a download URL. That gs URL simply will not work.  It doesn't matter how you added the file to the storage bucket.

Comment: So simply you are telling me to upload images using my app code or otherwise it wont work like this..

Comment: You can upload the image any way you want. No matter what you do, you will still need to generate a download URL to store in your database so it can be loaded into your app.  The gs URL you have now will not work.

Comment: Okay, so how do i get the download URL, can you share any code .

Comment: I linked that in my answer.

Comment: Okay got it. Thank you.

Comment: you are saying right ,thanks for that but my problem is My App is a eCommerce  App so i can't give them any option to upload images to Firebase Storage.So I think i only have option to make another app which share same database and do these things in that app..Do you have any better solution to make it work.